# Entity framework savechanges error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, savechanges

I have a wizard step in which a user fills in fields. I then use json to save the values into my database for each wizard step. 
However, in my repository I have my savechanges(). But it wont save the changes, instead it throws an error:

> Entities in 'NKImodeledmxContainer.SelectedQuestion' participate in the 'QuestionSelectedQuestion' relationship. 0 related 'Question' were found. 1 'Question' is expected.

Anyone know how to get rid of the error? Do I have to get the ID from Question and save it aswell to my database or can I change something in EF so the error message is not getting thrown?

This is my post in my controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult AnswerForm(int id, SelectedQuestionViewModel model)
    {
        bool result = false;
        var goalCardQuestionAnswer = new GoalCardQuestionAnswer();
        goalCardQuestionAnswer.SelectedQuestion = new SelectedQuestion();

        goalCardQuestionAnswer.SelectedQuestion.Id = model.QuestionID;
        goalCardQuestionAnswer.Comment = model.Comment;
        goalCardQuestionAnswer.Grade = model.Grade;

            if (goalCardQuestionAnswer.Grade != null)
            {

                    answerNKIRepository.SaveQuestionAnswer(goalCardQuestionAnswer);
                    answerNKIRepository.Save();
                    result = true;
                    return Json(result);                   
            }

       answerNKIRepository.SaveQuestionAnswer(goalCardQuestionAnswer);
       answerNKIRepository.Save();

        return Json(result);
    }
```

My Repository

```
    public class AnswerNKIRepository
{
    private readonly NKImodeledmxContainer db = new NKImodeledmxContainer();

    public List<SelectedQuestion> GetAllSelectedQuestionsByGoalCardId(int goalCardId)
    {
        return db.SelectedQuestion.Where(question => question.GoalCard.Id == goalCardId).ToList();
    }

    public void SaveQuestionAnswer(GoalCardQuestionAnswer goalCardQuestionAnswer)
    {
        db.GoalCardQuestionAnswer.AddObject(goalCardQuestionAnswer);
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

This is my ViewModel:

```
 public class SelectedQuestionViewModel
{

    public int? Grade { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public string SelectedQuestionText { get; set; }
    public int QuestionID { get; set; }
}
```

This is my database model:

[image]

Comment: You are not showing what is happening in your repository which is probably most important part of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception complains that `SelectedQuestion.Question` is a required navigation property but you don't set this property in your code. Try to load the question by Id from the repository and set it to the `SelectedQuestion.Question` reference: Replace this line ...

```
goalCardQuestionAnswer.SelectedQuestion.Id = model.QuestionID;
```

...by...

```
goalCardQuestionAnswer.SelectedQuestion.Question =
    answerNKIRepository.GetQuestionById(model.QuestionID);
```

And in your repository add the method:

```
public Question GetQuestionById(int id)
{
    return db.Question.Single(q => q.Id == id);
}
```

Comment: With that code i get following error message: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: At the line you suggested I should replace: "goalCardQuestionAnswer.SelectedQuestion.Question = 
    answerNKIRepository.GetQuestionById(model.QuestionID);"

Comment: Is there anyway to not get Question enitity involved in my controller? I would prefer just to use SelectedQuestion and GoalCardQuestionAnswer to be used. I need to fill the foreign key in my GoalCardQuestionAnswer entity by SelectedQuestion ID

Comment: @ps__: Can you check in the debugger if one of the objects `goalCardQuestionAnswer` or `goalCardQuestionAnswer.SelectedQuestion` or `answerNKIRepository` or `model` is `null`? I can't imagine the first two are `null` because you create them with `new` in the lines before.

Comment: Your code creates a *new* `SelectedQuestion`. Don't you want this? Does the `SelectedQuestion` already exist in the DB?

Comment: Both `goalCardQuestionAnswer` and `goalCardQuestionAnswer.SelectedQuestion` is null. Model is filled though.

Comment: `SelectedQuestion` does not exist in database as of now. Its getting filled by the user in this step.

Comment: @ps__: But how can `goalCardQuestionAnswer` and `goalCardQuestionAnswer.SelectedQuestion` be `null`??? You are creating them with `new` at the beginning of your controller action. Did you remove these lines? You shouldn't.

Comment: @ps__: If you would have exposed foreign keys as properties in your model you could have set `goalCardQuestionAnswer.SelectedQuestion.QuestionId = model.QuestionID`. But you don't have a FK property, then you *must* assign a `Question` entity as shown in my answer. However, you can expose foreign keys in the model. The model designer in Visual Studio has a checkbox to enable this option (in .NET 4, not in .NET 3.5).

Comment: I solved, I hade to change my linq in repository to `SelectedQuestion` instead of `Question`, thanks for giving me help!